# Android developing cross to iOS platform

Tags: android, ios

i am recently developing an enterprise mobile app, using Android Studio, and of course java on the code and XML on the layouts code. As all apps, i need it to be running on the iOS OS too, so my question is: Is there any software, or SDK that could transform my Android Studio apk or my code into an IOS app? If there's not, what are my options? the app that im developing its not simple so its getting bigger and bigger, so programing again on an IOS SDK its not really a solution right now. Help please.

Comment: "plataform"? anyway, why would you want to port an Android app to a router?

Comment: thanks for the correction, and with IOS OS i mean Iphone or Ipad Operating System. Not the IOS on the routers.

Comment: that's spelled "iOS" then. As well as "iPhone" and "iPad" are spelled with a lowercase "i". The OS called "IOS" **is** Cisco's router system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [j2objc](https://github.com/google/j2objc), but it's still experimental. If you want to develop cross platfrom native app, you should try tools and frameworks like [Titanium](https://appcelerator.com/) or [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

Comment: I looked into Xamarin, but it uses C# code even for the android development, i'll read more about AppCelerator, and see if does the magic. thank you

Comment: By experience, let me tell you that the *write once run everywere* approach it's not optimal. You should always decline your project for best suit to each platform, even if you use a framework like the above.